# uhttpd crashes when requesting the luci index for the first time

Tags: crash, openwrt, httpd

I installed OpenWRT (`ATTITUDE ADJUSTMENT (Bleeding Edge, r33556)`) on my TP-Link Wifi router (`TL-WR1043ND`) and after getting sshd and some basic stuff running it sat on my desk for a couple weeks and now I continued installing it.

I installed [luci](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/luci.essentials) with `uhttpd` which is pretty straightforward with `opkg` and tried accessing it with a browser. However, each time I start the server and try to open `index.html`, the server seems to silently crash and I have no idea why.

### Context

For installation purposes, my laptop (temporarily `192.168.0.1`) acts as a router itself (which works perfectly well). I assigned the router (`pinky`) the LAN IP `192.168.0.2` and disabled the WAN interface. So, my network configuration looks as follows:

```
# cat /etc/config/network
config interface 'loopback'
        option ifname 'lo'
        option proto 'static'
        option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
        option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config interface 'lan'
        option ifname 'eth0.1'
        option proto 'static'
        option ipaddr '192.168.0.2'
        option netmask '255.255.255.0'
        option gateway '192.168.0.1'
        option dns '134.130.4.1 134.130.5.1'

config interface 'wan'
        option ifname 'eth0.2'
        option proto 'none'

config switch
        option name 'rtl8366rb'
        option reset '1'
        option enable_vlan '1'

config switch_vlan
        option device 'rtl8366rb'
        option vlan '1'
        option ports '1 2 3 4 5t'

config switch_vlan
        option device 'rtl8366rb'
        option vlan '2'
        option ports '0 5t'
```

The specified dns refers to servers in my local network (the network my VPN tunnel leads to, to be precise). At any rate, this config is obviously temporary, until I'm confident to connect the router to the internet proper.

I tried several configurations for uhttpd but all lead to the same behaviour. First I ran the server without SSL support and then installed `luci-ssl` hoping it might fix the issue. I now reverted the config to absolute minimum:

```
# cat /etc/config/uhttpd
config 'uhttpd' 'main'
        option 'listen_http' '0.0.0.0:80'
        option 'home'        '/www'
```

### Problem

When I start the server it appears to boot up nicely:

```
 2183 root      1132 S    /usr/sbin/uhttpd -f -h /www -r pinky -n 3 -p 0.0.0.0 80
```

However, once I open `http://192.168.0.2` or `http://192.168.0.2/index.html` (from my laptop, that is) the process just disappears (i.e. crashes). And if I start the server manually, it tells me:

```
# /usr/sbin/uhttpd -f -h /www -r pinky -n 3 -p 0.0.0.0 80
getaddrinfo(): Servname not supported for ai_socktype
Error: No sockets bound, unable to continue
```

And I have no idea what that is supposed to tell me.

***How can I narrow down the problem and fix it?***

### Versions

`luci` is at version `svn-r9819-1` and `uhttpd` is at version `2013-05-16-7a6811b705d6cca54b1367459fa19bb6d1234c45`.

Answer (score 0):

I now [switched the http server serving `luci`](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/luci.essentials#luci.on.lighttpd) from `uhttpd` to `lighttpd` installing only the packages:

```
opkg install lighttpd lighttpd-mod-cgi luci-mod-admin-full luci-theme-openwrt libiwinfo
```

And it works well. Although [`lighttpd`](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/http.overview#web.server.packages.in.openwrt.repository) is four times the size of `uhttpd`, I can spare the space and gather the former to be more robust and tested anyway (and more configurable).